# What special kind of IMAP mailbox is "foo@user.alice."?

Tags: imap, mailbox, cyrus

Preparing an IMAP server migration and checking for connected components of users sharing mailboxes, we stumbled over a some unusual ACL patterns observed when running `listaclmailbox *` in `cyradm` (server is running Cyrus IMAP 2.5.6):

```
foo@user.alice.:
  anyone lrs
```

Obviously, `alice` shared something readable to any user logged in. We're unused to this syntax: usually, we expected something like

```
user.alice.foo:
  alice lrswipkxtecda
  bob lrs
```

when alice shared her mailbox `user.alice.foo` with `bob`. What is the `@` indicating, why is there a trailing dot `.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a folder user.alice.!foo in mailboxes.db, and either there's a bug in 2.5.x, or you switched on virtual domains at some point.

The '!' character is used as the domain separator, which makes the folder name ambiguous.

This folder is probably invisible to user alice right now.